# What is the best practice for debug touch input in Unity 3D?

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine

I am recently new on this Unity development, and I tried a simple Android game with touch inputs. I thought when you run the app on a device you would receive the debug logs, but after some head bashing I realised that wasn't the case.

My question is while developing a mobile app which requires you to have some touch input, it's really frustrating to build and run all the time. Isn't there a more developer-friendly approach to this? Like using an emulator or something like [JRebel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroTurnaround#Products) which would be doing some hot code replacement for you?

What would be the best approach to take on this?

Comment: I always test in editor player using mouse input until everthing works then I deploy to mobile devices.

Comment: @Alex testing during development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is while developing a mobile app which requires you to
>   have some touch input , its really frustrating to build and run all
>   the time isn't there a more developer friendly approach to this ?

Try [UnityRemote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unity3d.androidremote&hl=en). You can control an application running in the editor using touch input in your mobile device. You may experience some lag, but it's great for debug and can save you a lot of time.

Comment: will unityremote enable me to get debug.log statements in my console when say a touch event happents at device ?

Comment: @add9: Yes. Basically it simply allow you to use your touch device as input of an application running in the editor.